# Hostgator giving 404 error

Tags: wordpress, hosting, web-hosting

So, the website is http://www.abeillebridal.com/

I've set up Wordpress with woocommerce on it and it worked perfectly fine for hours. I took a quick break and when I get back to refresh the page it's suddenly returning 404s. This wasnt the first time too, the first one I thought I messed up something so I made a clean reinstall.

Everything is still on the public_html folder and I tried to remove the .htaccess but no success.

I also tried hostgator chat support but it's just horrible.

Help?

Comment: are you sure? I've tested in on different PCs and different IPs and it says 404

Comment: Yes, now you (or someone) renamed `index.php` to `index.php.bk`, and I can see the directory contents of your "public_html".

Comment: Do you have your `hosts` file set up with additional entries for that domain?

Comment: @LaughDonor yes, Im trying to find the problem

Comment: Seemed like I had a duplicate pointer on the DNS... Thanks anyway!